# How to programmatically look out for a specific log message from a particular class file in Java for Jboss application that uses slf4j/logstash?

Tags: java, jboss, log4j, slf4j

I need to look out for specific log message from a particular class file in my JBoss application.It uses slf4j/logstash. Is there a way I can capture this programmatically(java)?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried writing a custom Appender?